# CKEditor: How to disable automatic 'url to anchor' parsing?

Tags: hyperlink, ckeditor, fckeditor

Is there some way or some config setting to disable the automatic parsing of an url in CKEditor?

When I type `wwww.google.com`, it's automatically parsed to 
`<a href="http://wwww.google.com">wwww.google.com</a>`

How to disable this automatic 'url to anchor' parsing?

Comment: I believe an option to remove auto-parsing of urls is a current feature request: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/6307